# Form type date with default values

Tags: symfony

I want to creat a date field with only year selector. First i creat this field in form like this.

```
->add('visitDate',
                       'date',
                        array('label' => false,
                              'translation_domain' => 'messages',
                              'required'    => false,
                              'widget'      => 'choice',
                              'input'       => 'array',
                              'years'       => range(date('Y'), 2006),
                              'months'      => range(1,12),
                              'days'        => range(1,31),
                              'empty_value' => array('month'=> 1, 'day' => 1),
                        )
```

And hide the month and day field in twig. If i post my form the month and day field get post the value "null" instead of 1.

Can someone give me a tip why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

you seem to  have a typo

change

```
                          'months'      => range(1,12),
                          'days'        => range(1,31),
                          'empty_value' => array('month'=> 1, 'day' => 1),
```

to

```
                          'months'      => range(1,12),
                          'days'        => range(1,31),
                          'empty_value' => array('months'=> 1, 'days' => 1),
```

this should be it,
otherwise if this doesn´t work you have thousand ways to rome if you want the user to only choose the year you could do sth. like

```
// let the user post the $year as string "2015"
$time = new DateTime();
$time->modify('first day of January '.$year);
```

Comment: unfortunately the typo do not fix my issue. Where i set this $time value? In Form or Controller?

Comment: This fix my issue 'data' => date('Y-m-d'),

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 6.2, to set the current date as the default value for the date field, you can assign a new instance of \DateTime() to the data attribute. This will populate the field with the current date when the form is rendered.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ->add('total')
        ->add('date',  DateType::class, [
            'widget' => 'choice',
            'data'   => new \DateTime(), // current date
        ])
    ;
}
```